# NFL Combine Worst Performances

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl

I am attempting to clean a data set of NFL Combine performances; because some values of the data set are physically impossible, I would like to know the best and worst performances in the combine (to eliminate data that is not within this range). Obtaining data for the best performances in the combine is simple. Obtaining data for the worst performances in the combine, however, has proven difficult; I have searched through multiple websites with no luck.

I would like to know the following:

1. What is the slowest twenty-yard shuttle in the NFL Combine of all time, and by who?
2. What is the shortest vertical in the NFL Combine of all time, and by who?
3. What is the shortest broad jump in the NFL Combine of all time, and by who?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I manually searched through Pro Football Reference.

According to the site:

1. The slowest twenty-yard shuttle in the NFL Combine is [5.56 seconds by Isaiah Thompson in 2011](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/draft/2011-combine.htm).
2. The shortest vertical in the NFL Combine is [17.5 inches by Josue Matias in 2015](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/draft/2015-combine.htm).
3. The shortest broad jump in the NFL Combine is [74 inches by Stefon Wheeler in 2006](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/draft/2006-combine.htm).